# SSRS Auto Generating all columns from Dataset into tablix (Report Builder 3.0)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

Is there a simple way to just auto generate every field/column from a dataset into a flat table/tablix in SSRS without making it a matrix?  Seems like something that should be so easy, rather than having to drag each and every column over.  Not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

My dataset returns about 180 columns, dragging them all over would be painful.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated!  I'm using Report Builder 3.0 by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using the Table Wizard http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255273.aspx#CreateTable You can specify the required columns quite easily and Report Builder creates the table - for hundreds of columns that might be slightly easier than the standard Designer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the Table Wizard in Report Builder?

See [Creating a Basic Table Report](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255273.aspx#CreateTable).

You can specify the required columns quite easily by just selecting them in the Wizard and Report Builder creates the table - for hundreds of columns that might be slightly easier than the standard Designer.

You can only use the built-in Wizard themes, but it's probably easier to format all of the cells in one go or by find/replace in the RDL file than specifying almost 200 fields.

Comment: I've tried this, but even when I do this a lot of the fields seem to be SUMMED, and I have to go into each field expression and remove the SUM() .  Not sure what I'm missing

Comment: This worked beautifully for me.  I added all the columns to the Details section.