# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 Auto-generate columns for flat table (not matrix grouping) to avoid manual dragging? possible?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2008-r2

I must be missing something very obvious!

If I have a simple query (SELECT * FROM Table) which has 200 columns - rather than dragging each of my dataset columns onto my table object in design mode, is there any way to have those 200 columns auto built to that table, or a new table? THE CATCH IS - I don't want to do any grouping, summing, etc.. Just a flat table.

** IF I try to use the Table Wizard, it eventually brings me to that "Arrange Fields" box which provides Column groups, Row groups and Values.  I only want "Columns" generated, not any kind of Matrix grouping.  Just a flat table, so if my dataset returns 1000 rows, I want a table that has 200 columns, and 1000 rows.

Is this not possible in Report Builder?  I'm completely stumped!!  Help very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I Am not understanding this issue, Could you use headers or footers or some other mechanism that will aggregate the values for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS Auto Generating all columns from Dataset into tablix (Report Builder 3.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916909/ssrs-auto-generating-all-columns-from-dataset-into-tablix-report-builder-3-0)

Answer (score 1):

The wizard WILL do exactly what you're looking for - when you get to the page in the wizard with the 3 boxes (row/column groups + details), just put all of your fields into the Details box - neither of the grouping boxes are required fields.

Leave the formatting alone on the following page, and you're set.